Simplification of square root of complex-valued expression
I want to simplify a sqrt of a complex formula,
Simplify[Sqrt[Exp[4 I k a]],k>0&&a>0]

where a and k are complex. The final result should be
Exp[2 I k a]?

I try to use several commands, such as Refine, ComplexExpand, ExpToTrig. But they all fail. What command can complete this simplification?

I don't understand the question. If a and k are complex, what does it mean that they are greater than zero?

Exp[2 I k a]?  And what about -Exp[2 I k a]
?

The final resullt assuming Element[{a,k},Reals]  is   Exp[2 I k a],Exp[2 I k a+I Pi] (in accordance with @Artes comment). No further restriction a,kare necessary.

PowerExpand gives the answer you want, although that does not assume complex a and k.

@BillWatts: Did you think twice before having commented? The documentation says "The transformations made by PowerExpand are correct in general only if  c is an integer or a and  b are positive real numbers". Also Sqrt[Exp[4 I k a]] == Exp[2 I a k] /. {k -> 347/10, a -> 149/10} performs False as shown in my answer.

@user64494 That is because Mathematica is returning only the negative square root in your case as Sqrt[Exp[4 I k a]] // FullSimplify shows with your values of a and k.   Why don't you see what Exp[2 I k a]^2 gives you with a and k unspecified.

@user64494 Exp[2 I a k]^2 == Exp[4 I k a] /. {k -> 347/10, a -> 149/10} returns True

This is not true as
FindInstance[Sqrt[Exp[4 I k a]] != Exp[2 I a k ] && a > 0 && k > 0, {k, a}]


{{k -> 347/10, a -> 149/10}}

shows.
However, the relation holds under  the additional condition:
Simplify[Sqrt[Exp[4 I k a]], k > 0 && a > 0 && k*a <= Pi/4]


E^((2*I)*a*k)


You missed the second solution: Map[#^2 == Exp[4 I a k] &, {Exp[2 I a k], Exp[2 I a k + I Pi]} //    Simplify]  (*{True,True}*)

@UlrichNeumann: Are you serious? Sqrt[Exp[4 I k a]] == Exp[2 I a k + I Pi] /. {a -> 1, k -> 1/8} performs False.

Exp[2 I a k]^2 == Exp[4 I k a] /. {k -> 347/10, a -> 149/10} returns True

@BillWatts Thanks for your support!

@user64494 I'm serious, check documentation of Sqrt: FunctionRange[Sqrt[x], x, y, Complexes]  (*(Re[y] == 0 && Im[y] >= 0) || Re[y] > 0*) !!!

@user64494 Your example is flawed.  One side of your equation returns the positive square root while the other side returns the negative square root.  Since they are not equal, the equation returns false.  Nevertheless, both are correct square roots.

Exp[4 I k a] == Exp[2 I a k + I Pi]^2 /. {a -> 1, k -> 1/8} returns True
